# Giving Transport unknown from frontend for socket.io, express JS application. It is microservice architecture where ALB is used

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, websocket, socket.io, aws-application-load-balancer

I am using socket.io on server and client in a microservices architecture, ALB is used, where a API on to which server socket is running is listening to /api/doctor-desk from ALB listener rule.

My websocket is working. But my normal REST api's are bereaking, giving 400 error

`{"code":0,"message":"Transport unknown"}`

Thi is my **server** code

```
let io;

module.exports = {
  init: (httpServer, path) => {
    io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
      path: path,
      transports: ["websocket", "polling"], // Specify the allowed transport(s)

      cors: {
        origin: "*",
      },
    });
    return io;
  },
  getIO: () => {
    if (!io) {
      throw new Error("Socket.IO is not initialized!");
    }
    return io;
  },
};
```

and below is my **client** code

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

// export const socket = io("http://192.168.153.138:7006/", {
export const socket = io("https://api-dev.myurl.in", {
  reconnection: true,
  transports: ["websocket"],
  path: "/api/doctor-desk",
});
```

**index.js**

```
const serverConfig = require("./server-config");
const app = require("./app");
const cors = require("cors");

const { init, getIO } = require("../socket");
const onConnection = require("./onConnection");

app.use(cors());

const server = app.listen(serverConfig.port);

const socketPath = "/api/doctor-desk";

init(server, socketPath).on("connection", (socket) => {
  onConnection(getIO, socket);
});

console.log(`listening on http://${serverConfig.host}:${serverConfig.port}`);
```

and if I remove the path my socket stops working and my REST api's work